# Accessing iDRAC6 Express on DellR610

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac

[**Update**: I had the ethernet cable in port **4** not port **1**! Putting it in port 1 fixed the problem.]

Hi I have just recently acquired a DellR610 to test configurations and
experiment with. It has 2 X E5504, 12GB ram, and no drives at present. I am
just trying to update the firmware and other things first, then the RAID
controllers, then drives, etc.

After reading around on the best way to update all the firmware components,
I used the Dell Repository Manager, and basically created a "repository" for
all the latest R610 firmware / BIOS "updates" using the repository manager. I then created a bootable iso from that, used rufus to
flash it to a thumb drive and then booted the R610 from that. That ran
though all 108 updates, etc and updated various pieces of firmware, the
main BIOS to 6.4.0, the iDrac, the broadcom NIC controllers, etc.

I have one problem with the [LifeCycle update not sticking](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/906/t/19617247). I am trying to resolve that but in doing so I might need to get the iDRAC6 working. However I have reset the iDRAC6 to default settings, and then I try and configure a static IP on my local network but I can't bring any page up... (I have tried switching on various settings like IPMI and off again but I still can't get through on anything)

Since the iDRAC6 is an express model not the enterprise model, do I just stick the ethernet cable in the NIC1? Do I need some special BIOS configuration in the main BIOS? Right now I have just configured this with defaults and the following settings:

[image: iDRAC6 Configuration]

[image: DRAC6 ipV4 Configuration]

[image: DRAC6 Lan User Configuration]

Maybe this is because the LifeCycle Controller is stuck at version 1.2.0.8, A00 ?

Thanks for any help / pointers...!

Comment: Yup stick a network cable into first ethernet port.

Comment: Gahhhhckkk! It turns out the eathernet was plugged into the last eathernet port and not the first! Stupid stupid goof on my part... I now have the iDRAC up and responding... Thanks!

Comment: Happens to all of us :) I bet you spent a lot of time writing this question pictures and all only to realize "wrong hole"

Comment: @Dan Could always be worse. People are typically ***much*** less understanding than servers when you put your cable into the wrong hole.